# Saving an object to Chrome storage, but getting different results back on retrieval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm using an object with information for a bookmark tagging system that needs to persist across Chrome sessions, so I'm trying to save it to local storage and update it whenever a new bookmark is created.

When I create a new bookmark, I fire a function to see if there are now any other bookmarks with the same tag as the new bookmark. This organizes bookmarks into "tag groups" that function kind of like dynamic folders.

When I set the storage object, the object being stored has all the data I'd expect. However, as soon as I get the same object out of storage, one of the nested objects mysteriously turns to `null`. See console output: the top object is just before the set call in function `updateStorage`. The bottom is what I get back when I "get" that object from storage. Notice the tagGroups bookmarks are now null. The bookmarks themselves are still there, it's only in the tag group object that they disappear. I've spent a full day and night messing around with this trying to get it to work.

[image: console output]

Here is the model code. I included everything for context, but the most relevant pieces are the createNewBookmark, updatePrimaryTreeWithTagGroups, and updateStorage methods.

**UPDATE**: I've edited the code to make all the changes to the bookmarks tree before setting/getting anything from storage, then making a final call to update storage with the resulting object. I'm literally storing one thing, one time, and getting back another whenever I try to retrieve.

```
function PrimaryBookmarksTree(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, this.findOrCreate.bind(this));
}

PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.findOrCreate = function(result){
    if (result.bookmarksTree != undefined){
        this.bookmarks = result.bookmarksTree.bookmarks;
        this.title = result.bookmarksTree.title;
        this.tagGroups = result.bookmarksTree.tagGroups;
        console.log(this);
    } else {
        this.bookmarks = [];
        this.title = "Marinade Bookmarks";
        this.tagGroups = [];
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"bookmarksTree": this}, function(){console.log("New tree created!")});
        console.log(this);
    }
}

function Bookmark(name, tags, url){
    this.name = name;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.url = url;
    this.dateCreated = this.date();
}

function TagGroup(tag){
    this.bookmarks = [];
    this.tag = tag;
}

//called by controller when user tags a new bookmark via the extension
PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.createNewBookmark = function(name, tags, url){
    var newBookmark = new Bookmark(name, tags, url);
    this.bookmarks.push(newBookmark);
    this.tagGroups = this.updatePrimaryTreeWithTagGroups();
    this.updateStorage(this);       

}

PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.updatePrimaryTreeWithTagGroups = function(){ 
    var tagsForGrouping = this.getTagsWithMultipleBookmarks(this.bookmarks);
    for(j=0;j<tagsForGrouping.length;j++){
        this.tagGroups.push(this.buildTagGroup(tagsForGrouping[j]));
    }
    return this.tagGroups;
}

PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.getTagsWithMultipleBookmarks = function(bookmarks){
    var tagsToCheck = this.pluck(bookmarks, "tags");
    var tagCounts = tagsToCheck.reduce(function (obj, curr){
        if (typeof obj[curr] == 'undefined') {
            obj[curr] = 1;
        } else {
            obj[curr] += 1;
        }
        return obj;
    }, {});
    var tagGroups = this.filter(tagCounts, function(x){return x > 1});
    return tagGroups;
}

PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.buildTagGroup = function(tag){
    tagGroup = new TagGroup(tag);
    for(i=0;i<this.bookmarks.length;i++){
        if(this.bookmarks[i].tags[0] == tag){
            tagGroup.bookmarks.push(this.bookmarks[i]);
        }
    }
    if (tagGroup.bookmarks.length != 0){
        return tagGroup;
    }
}


PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.updateStorage = function(updatedTree){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedTree));
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"bookmarksTree": updatedTree}, function(){console.log("final storage complete")});
}
```

Comment: If you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(.........))` just before `chrome.storage.sync.set` will the output contain those objects?

Comment: Maybe you're hitting the [sync quota](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#properties) limits: either per item or total?

Comment: @wOxxOm i thought about that, but i'm not getting the corresponding runtime error (and my test data object is really quite small). The console does display the correct objects, yes.

Comment: I would test it on `chrome.storage.local`...

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the suggestion...no dice though! i'm going to restructure this completely now and try something new...but if anyone is reading this and has another suggestion, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are always setting `this.tagGroups` to `undefined` when you retrieve your data from the sync storage:

```
PrimaryBookmarksTree.prototype.findOrCreate = function(result){
    if (result.bookmarksTree != undefined){
        this.bookmarks = result.bookmarksTree.bookmarks;
        this.title = result.bookmarksTree.title;
        this.tagGroups = result.tagGroups; // should be result.bookmarksTree.tagGroups
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, yes, thank you. I was testing to see if the tag group's bookmarks would still be null if I made tagGroups a separate storage object from the bookmarksTree and forgot to switch it back later when that didn't work. However, still getting null once I fixed this oversight...and slowly going insane.

Comment: Just a question, have you extracted a subset of the underscorejs functions and defined them on your `PrimaryBookmarksTree` object? Because I see that you are using `pluck` and `filter` but on `this`?

Comment: yep, I was reimplementing underscore for another practice project and decided to just write them into my object rather than use the whole library for a couple of simple functions. is that a bad idea, or just a little weird without that context?

Comment: It was mainly to understand the context, and to be able to test the code. I ran your code (using underscorejs) and `tagGroups` always contains null values, even before setting your object into the storage. Tested with `createNewBookmark('bookmark1', ['tag1', 'tag2'], 'http://fake-url');` and `createNewBookmark('bookmark2', ['tag1', 'tag3'], 'http://fake-url2');` Is it the expected call syntax? If so I think the pb is more related to your `getTagsWithMultipleBookmarks` function than to the storage.

Comment: I see...I've been temporarily assuming only one tag per bookmark for simplicity's sake, so I'm not sure about the results with more than one. When I stepped through the function with Chrome's dev tools that function was returning `tagGroups` with non-null values. Maybe try with a single tag per and see if that changes anything? I'm curious if by stepping through the function I'm changing certain conditions...